# How to reset mysql password

Tags: mysql

When I'm trying to login to my Mysql as root(`./mysql -u root -p`) it is showing an error as given below

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Is this due to password expiration? Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Log in as root and stop the mysql daemon.
2. Now start up the mysql daemon and skip the grant tables which store the passwords.

   mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
3. You should be able to connect without password now

Type the following commands

```
mysql --user=root mysql

update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

Answer (score -1):

Several things could be going wrong.

1. You could be using the incorrect password to log in
2. The password could be expired
3. Mysql could not be configured to allow root to log in

Try the following:

1. `sudo su -l` # log in as root
2. once you're root, `./mysql` and see if that permits you to connect.

If that fails, try the steps listed here:

http://www.howtoforge.com/reset-forgotten-mysql-root-password